# How can I solve this hive sql problem? (Like join in Hive)

Tags: hadoop, hive

I know Hive only provide equi join. For example, below sql statement.
select *
from A join B
on A.c1 = B.c2
where 1=1;

But I want to execute Like join Query in Hive. For example, below sql statement.
select *
from A join B
on A.c1 like B.c2
where 1=1;

Please let me know if you know the solution in Hive.

Answer (score 0):

How about -

```
ON A.c1 LIKE concat('%',B.c2,'%')
```

concat will concatenate % to the c2 data so like operator will work properly.
whole sql will be like -

```
select * from A join B on A.c1 LIKE concat('%',B.c2,'%') where 1=1;
```

version - hive 2.1.1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, unfortunately this solution occurred Semantic Exception...

Comment: what is your hive version?

Comment: I'm using HDP 2.6.2 and Hive 1.2.1000

Comment: This will work only in case of hive 2.x and higher. So, for you probably there is not many options. can you try this way `select * from A join B on 1=1 where  A.c1 LIKE concat('%',B.c2,'%') `